# Codeigniter; Calendaring Class: destacar o mês atual num calendário anual

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, calendar

Eu fiz um método que escreve uma VIEW com uma tabela de calendário que mostra todos os meses de um ano usando a biblioteca [Calendaring Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html). Ele funciona bem, e retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
<?php

class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public function this_year() {
        $data['title'] = 'Calendar: ' . date('Y');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $prefs = array(
            'local_time' => 'none',
            'start_day' => 'sunday',
            'month_type' => 'long',
            'day_type' => 'short',
            'show_next_prev' => FALSE,
            'show_other_days' => TRUE,
            'template' => '
        {table_open}<table class="table table-condensed">{/table_open}
        {heading_row_start}<tr class="info">{/heading_row_start}
        {cal_cell_start_today}<td class="today">{/cal_cell_start_today}
        {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-day">{/cal_cell_start_other}
    '
        );
        $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
        $data['calendar'] = '<table class="table-calendar"><tr>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
            if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
                $data['calendar'].= '</tr><tr>';
            }
            else {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
            }
        }
        $data['calendar'].= '</tr></table>';
        $this->template->load('template/index', __CLASS__ . "/" . __FUNCTION__, $data);
    }

}
```

Mas eu não encontrei uma maneira de destacar apenas o mês atual usando um modelo no CSS da tabela. Quando eu altero o estilo da linha `{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}` ([ref](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html#creating-a-calendar-template)), ele modifica todos os rótulos dos meses:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando os métodos e padrões do [tutorial básico](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html#creating-a-calendar-template) (mesmo código). Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria desta forma:

```
<?php

class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

    public function this_year() {


        $data['title'] = 'Calendar: ' . date('Y');
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $prefs = array(
            'local_time' => 'none',
            'start_day' => 'sunday',
            'month_type' => 'long',
            'day_type' => 'short',
            'show_next_prev' => FALSE,
            'show_other_days' => TRUE,
            'template' => '
        {table_open}<table class="table table-condensed">{/table_open}
        {heading_row_start}<tr class="info">{/heading_row_start}
        {cal_cell_start_today}<td class="today">{/cal_cell_start_today}
        {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-day">{/cal_cell_start_other}
    '
        );
        $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
        $data['calendar'] = '<table class="table-calendar"><tr>';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) { 
            if($date("m")==$i) $mes_ativo = 'ativo'; else $mes_ativo = ''; // se o mês correspondente for ativo (mes atual), aplicamos a classe ativo (podes usar um css com background color)
            if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td class='{$mes_ativo}'>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
                $data['calendar'].= '</tr><tr>';
            }
            else {
                $data['calendar'].= "<td>{$this->calendar->generate(date('Y'), $i)}</td>";
            }
        }
        $data['calendar'].= '</tr></table>';
        $this->template->load('template/index', __CLASS__ . "/" . __FUNCTION__, $data);
    }

}
```

Note que adicionei:

```
if($date("m")==$i) $mes_ativo = 'ativo'; else $mes_ativo = '';
```

Neste caso, se o mês correspondente for o mês que estiver dentro do increment, irá inserir a tag ativo, que por sua vez, colocará um background (de acordo com o css que você fizer)

CSS

```
.ativo {
     background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: De fato, eu estava concentrado em mudar o estilo da linha `{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}` que não atentei que é mais prático alterar a tabela onde o mês é gerado. Eu também cheguei a uma solução estendendo a classe CI_Calendar, mas vou marcar sua resposta porque ela é uma solução mais simples. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Também é possível [expandir](http://192.168.56.201/codeigniter/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=extending#extending-native-libraries) a classe `CI_Calendar` para fazer com que o método `generate()` passe o seu valor `$month` para o método `parse_template()`. Assim, ao gerar o template declarado, `parse_template()` vai poder usar o valor passado pra destacar a linha `{heading_row_start}<tr>{/heading_row_start}`:

`CI_Calendar::parse_template($month), 483`:

```
if($val == 'heading_row_start'){
  if( $month == date('m')){
    $this->replacements[$val] = '<tr class="info">';
  }
}
else{
  $this->replacements[$val] = $match[1];
}
```